# Calling sql-specific operator/function (Full Text search) while still using ORM

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, linq-to-sql

My database is postgress and I allready have it scaffolded and properly mapped to MVCs. Now I have encountered a problem, because now I need a way to call full-text search, like in this simple query

```
Select * from fl_file storage where fl_file.text @@ 'dog cat rain';
```

I haven't found a way how to write a LINQ query that will be translated in above sql string, except making some LINQ extension method that would call to stored procedure which would just execute full text search.

I find this approach "a bit" clumsy, and I'm pretty shure that if I'll do it, I'll just reinvent a wheel (probably square one) so any help with solving this problem would be apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way to do this, though I firstly didn't know how to combine LINQ with pure SQL. In .net core its FromSql in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational assembly

```
String str = "dog cat rain";
_context.FlFile.FromSql(@"select * from fl_file where fts @@ plainto_tsquery({0})", str)
```